# How to link to a file directory within Node?

Tags: html, node.js

I currently have a node server set up with the ability to upload files onto the server. I would like to have the ability for the user to be able to click on a link to open up the file directory to see all the files that have been uploaded to the server. I would like to know if this would be possible.

```
<a href="localhost:80/testexample/uploads"> UPLOADS DIRECTORY</a> 
<a href="localhost/testexample/uploads"> UPLOADS DIRECTORY</a> 

<a href="http://localhost/testexample/uploads"> UPLOADS DIRECTORY</a>

<a href="http://localhost/uploads"> UPLOADS DIRECTORY</a><br>
```

Example codes that I have tried but have not worked. Is it possible to carry out the functionality I intend to do?

I have tried doing it locally by putting the file directory path within an "a" tag and it displays the whole directory. I would like to do something similar with the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's possible, but it wont work merely by pointing them at a directory. Web browser work with HTML, not file systems. You would need to implement a web page that looks and behaves like a file system. Fortunately for you there are existing libraries that do this, like [file-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-browser).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into this and get back to you with the results!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can do it this way

```
<a href="/testexample/uploads"> UPLOADS DIRECTORY</a>
```

And from server upon a route hit you give back a page.

```
router.get('/testexample/uploads', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
}
```

This page can contain your images like this:

```
   <img src="/path-to-img-from-this-file"/>
   <img src="/path-to-img-from-this-file"/>
   <img src="/path-to-img-from-this-file"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will look into this!